# recursive js function without settimeout

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to rewrite a PHP function, which is working, into javascript because I need to do the work on the browser side and add event handlers to the objects I hope to add to my page.

The function takes an array of nodes, with parent child relationships, looks at a node, then at its children and then its children's children etc (until it finds the end of the tree).

The working PHP function:

```
//print nodes
function display_child_nodes($parent_id, $level) {
global $task_list, $index;
    if(isset($index[$parent_id]))
        {
            foreach ($index[$parent_id] as $id) {
                echo str_repeat("-", $level) . $task_list[$id]["title"] . "<br />";
                display_child_nodes($id, $level + 1);
            }
        }
}
display_child_nodes(0, 0);
```

The result of the PHP function looks like:
A

B

-C

-D

--E

F

G

This is the Javascript which I have tried to write, but I suspect the call to the function show_child_nodes form within that function is not correct JS...

The function produces the first node correctly, but stops as soon as it tries to analyse a child node, hence my suspicion that the call from within the function is the problem.

The javascript is receiving a json array from a php script, it contains a list of nodes (tasks) and their details, and the order_index array which is structured [parent_id1 => array[1,2,3], parent_id2 => [4,5], parent_id3 => [6,7,8]] etc... as in, each parent_id is a key with its child ids as the value.

Here is the JSON:

```
{"tasks":{"2":{"id":"2","title":"Task 2","desc":"Task 2 description","parent_id":"0"},"6":{"id":"6","title":"Task 6","desc":"Task 6 description","parent_id":"0"},"1":{"id":"1","title":"Task 1","desc":"Task 1 description","parent_id":"2"},"3":{"id":"3","title":"Task 3","desc":"Task 3 description","parent_id":"1"},"4":{"id":"4","title":"Task 4","desc":"Task 4 description","parent_id":"1"},"5":{"id":"5","title":"Task 5","desc":"Task 5 description","parent_id":"3"}},"order_index":{"0":["2","6"],"2":["1"],"1":["3","4"],"3":["5"]}}


            $.getJSON("get_items_hierarchy.php",function(data,status){

                var order_index = data.order_index;
                var tasks = data.tasks;
                var output = [];

                function show_child_nodes(parent_id,level){
                    if(order_index[order_index[parent_id]])
                        {
                            $.each(order_index[parent_id],function(index,id){
                                var margin = level * 40;
                                output.push('<div style="float: left; clear: left; margin-left: ' + margin + 'px">' + tasks[id]['title'] + '</div> ');
                                show_child_nodes(id, level + 1);
                            });
                        }
                }
                show_child_nodes(0,0);

            $.each(output,function(index,line){
                $("#tasks").append(line);
            });

    });
```

Comment: Can you add the code that sets `order_index` and `tasks`?

Comment: Edit made, thanks for getting back to me, have included all javascript and explanation of what its processing... hope this makes it clearer

Comment: It would be better to have example data to run the code against, e.g. the verbatim output from php.

Comment: cool, added the json as it is coming form my DB, via php script get_items_hierarchy.php

Comment: @RogerCurran I think my answer solves it. Works for me after that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to fix it.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Change this line:

```
if(order_index[order_index[parent_id]])
```

to:

```
if( order_index[parent_id] )
```

Comment: Woah!  Totally fixed it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in the algorithm itself, but the following part is likely to be a problem:

```
$.each(output, function(index,line){
    $("#tasks").append(line);
});
```

This code references the value of `output`, but:

1. `$.getJSON` is asynchronous, so the value won't be ready yet.
2. The variable is only accessible from inside the AJAX callback.

The code should be placed at the end of your AJAX callback function instead.

As mentioned by another answer, this statement is probably wrong:

```
if (order_index[order_index[parent_id]])
```

It might be just a typo, but the likely correct code is:

```
if (order_index[parent_id])
```